# Upgrade to 12.04, first boot stuck on Checking Battery State

Tags: upgrade, 12.04, boot-failure

I upgraded my 11.10 to 12.04 but it stuck on the first boot. I Alt+Shift+Del many times. But it does not go further.

I have Lenovo N200 machine with dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10. Switched to Ubuntu 11.04. And all was going fine since my last night upgrade activity.

How I can proceed further? I have taken my home folder backup. If I have to re-install it. 
Any help?

**Edit:** My graphic card is Intel Corporation GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphic Controller.

[image]

Comment: Is it some display driver issue? I search on the net. X system is not working. And I have to re-install GDM. (I know less about this under the hood stuff)

Comment: I have fresh re-installed 12.04. Was unable to recover my upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever seen this happen on my laptop when I installed the Proprietary ATI graphics driver when the integrated graphics were also enabled (switchable graphics issues).

If you have the model with an nvidia graphics device, you will want to try getting to a command prompt and reinstalling the video driver.

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Comment: I can go to shell prompt. But will it install nividia drivers without internet? I believe I have Intel video drivers. Intel Graphics Media Accelerator X3100 chipset. http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-67706#vid

Comment: To verify your VGA device from command prompt type: lspci | grep VGA

Comment: @Tahir please edit your question and put your video information there so it's not buried in a comment down here!

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the graphics manager gdm (in old ubuntus) or lightdm ( in newer ubuntus) is unable to capture the linux environment. i.e. Window manager is not able to take charge of the linux environment. To check if this is the case: Are you able to use ctrl + Alt + F1 to get to the virtual linux consoles? If yes, you should probably try to correct the gdm/lightdm installations and its config files. I won't be of much help here. A Web search should help though.